# Symfony 3 : using param from parameters.yml in entity ORM table prefix

Tags: symfony, parameters, doctrine-orm

I have an entity like that :

```
/**
 * MyEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_db_name.my_entity")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MyEntity
{

...

}
```

And I have this configuration in my parameters.yml :

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: my_db_name
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
```

Is it possible to use database_name parameter directly in the entity annotation like that ? :

```
/**
 * MyEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="%database_name%.my_entity")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MyEntity
{

...

}
```

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think so but why would you need such annotation?

Comment: @ReynierPM because I have two databases, and some entities have the same name. if I don't specify the database name in the Table annotation, the doctrine commands like schema:update don't work.

Comment: you can generate different bundle for different database and you cna use same name of entity

Comment: Specifying the table name will cause other problems as well especially if you try to make a relation between the two database.  You need two entity managers.  It's just the way Doctrine was designed.

Comment: @Cerad I have two entity manager, but all my entities are in the same Bundle and I can't put them in another one (for some non-technical reasons). And i didn't find any solution to configure my entities manager the way you are talking.

Comment: If you've two entitiy managers then switch them in demand when you need to use one DB or the other one, that's it!